# Why XmlReader reads in different block sizes

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

I noticed that XmlReader does not always read XML input in standard 4096 blocks.
In particular, if XmlReader discovers that first buffer ends with partial XML element name, then XML reader fills second buffer with partial data from first buffer, and only then reads more data into that buffer.

Why does XmlReader to that?

Why XmlReader would not always request to fill standard buffer with 4096 chars?

Code to reproduce weird XmlReader buffering behavior:

```
[TestClass]
public class XmlReaderTests
{
    public class DebugStreamReader : StreamReader
    {
        public DebugStreamReader(Stream stream) : base(stream) { }

        public override int Read(
            char[] buffer,
            int index,
            int count)
        {
            int readLength = base.Read(buffer, index, count);
            Trace.WriteLine("readLength: " + readLength + "; buffer.Length: " + buffer.Length + "; index: " + index + "; count: " + count);
            //Debug.Write("readLength: " + readLength);
            return readLength;
        }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void SuperLongXmlElementNameXmlReaderTest()
    {
        string elementName = new string('a', 20000);
        string xmlWithSuperLongElementName = "<" + elementName + ">test</" + elementName + ">";
        MemoryStream inputStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlWithSuperLongElementName));
        StreamReader sr = new DebugStreamReader(inputStream);
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(sr))
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                //string value = 
                reader.ReadString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
readLength: 4096; buffer.Length: 4097; index: 0; count: 4096
readLength: 1; buffer.Length: 4097; index: 4095; count: 1
readLength: 4097; buffer.Length: 8194; index: 4096; count: 4097
readLength: 8194; buffer.Length: 16388; index: 8193; count: 8194
readLength: 16388; buffer.Length: 32776; index: 16387; count: 16388
readLength: 7233; buffer.Length: 32776; index: 12768; count: 20007
readLength: 0; buffer.Length: 32776; index: 0; count: 32775
```

Comment: XmlReader reads to end of an xml object so it is not a fixed size.

Comment: I care about XmlReader implementation detail, because we extend XmlReader class in order to sanitize input from invalid XML chars.
Getting various buffer sizes and, especially, starting index for the buffer was totally unexpected and we spent probably about a week troubleshooting that issue.
So I am trying to learn the reasoning behind these various buffer sizes and how that helps XmlReader to parse input better.

Comment: @jdweng - I totally expected buffer to be smaller than standard 4096 chars size at the end of XML input.
However it was surprising to discover that buffer size and starting index can change in the middle of input processing.

Comment: @Jim Garrison - I just took a look at the source code of XmlReader class - it has 3429 lines of code.
I could not even find where they are using DefaultBufferSize constant that they defined. Finding out answer to my question by reading code would probably very time consuming exercise. I was hoping that somebody else on StackOverflow already figured out the answer.